# What is the purpose of the const overloads of std::begin and std::end?

Tags: c++, c++11

For `std::begin`, we have two overloads for containers:

```
template< class C > 
auto begin( C& c ) -> decltype(c.begin());
template< class C > 
auto begin( const C& c ) -> decltype(c.begin());
```

But the constness of `C` can be deduced by the usual template deduction rules, so it seems like the second overload is redundant. What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's reasonable to call `begin` (and `end`, for that matter) on an rvalue, provided we don't use the resulting iterator after the container has been destroyed. However, passing an rvalue to a parameter of the form `T&` will not work, which is where the second overload comes into play.

However, it may well be that we're dealing with a thoughtless transformation of a former [range-based for proposal wording](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2778.htm#container-concept-maps-container-concepts-member):

> **Add the following to the end of [container.concepts.member]**:
>
> ```
> template<Container C> concept_map Range<C> {
>     typedef C::iterator iterator;
>     iterator begin( C& c ) { return Container<C>::begin(c); }
>     iterator end( C& c )   { return Container<C>::end(c); } };
>
> template<Container C> concept_map Range<const C> {
>     typedef C::const_iterator iterator;
>     iterator begin( const C& c ) { return Container<C>::begin(c); }
>     iterator end( const C& c )   { return Container<C>::end(c); } };
> ```

When it became clear that concepts weren't going to make it into C++11, papers were amended, and all four function temploids were presumably translated into equivalent namespace-scope function templates. This had the (potentially unintended) consequence of rvalues being accepted, while the original code was simply intended to distinguish between differently qualified container types.

Note that a modern implementation of `begin`/`end` would use forwarding references instead - e.g.

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto begin(T&& t)
  -> decltype(std::forward<T>(t).begin()) {
    return    std::forward<T>(t).begin();
}
```

Comment: I'm not really convinced that this is intentional design. Getting `begin()` from a container without being able to get the `end()` from the same container doesn't seem useful.

Comment: @T.C. …unless you know an upper bound of its length. Anyway, I'm trying to trace down the paper.

Comment: Sure, except that there's no overload for array rvalues, whose length is actually in the type and so is definitely known at the call site. Personally, I suspect that it's an artifact from adapting the old [container concept maps](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2778.htm#container-concept-maps-container-concepts-member), which had separate `const` and non-`const` versions using `const_iterator` and `iterator`, respectively.

Comment: @T.C. AFAICS, rvalue arrays are an oversight (as rarely used). No LWG issues on this?

Comment: Nothing I'm aware of. Interesting how you think it is an oversight while I think it is evidence that it's not really meant to support rvalues :)

Comment: @T.C. The only reason why the `const` overload exists is rvalues, no? I mean, they didn't put it in there solely because of some archaic concept?

Comment: What about range based for: `for(auto i: {1, 2, 3}){}`?

Comment: @Columbo Are you sure? I have to define a `begin()` and an `end()` for range  based for to work.

Comment: @Galik Of course. Now what does that have to do with **std**::begin/end?

Comment: My theory is that they put it in because it was there before concepts were removed (and it was there before concepts were removed due to the use of iterator/const_iterator), and then for the post-removal cleanup they just applied a quasi-mechanical translation from the concepts-version to the no-concept-version.

Comment: Second time I see that it confuses someone :) https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/15037887#15037887

Comment: @T.C. My question was rather why the `const` overload in the concept map existed in the first place.

Comment: @Columbo Well, for the concept map, one uses `C::iterator` and the other uses `C::const_iterator`.

Comment: @T.C. Nevermind, I should've properly read that concept definition…