# Why does the STL provide a const overload for std::container::begin and std::container::end functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator

Take any STL container in mind which uses iterators.

The following is valid:

```
iterator begin();
const_iterator begin() const;
const_iterator cbegin() const;
```

Now I don't understand why the second line exists. Could someone provide a nice example where `iterator begin();` wouldn't work and it can't be replaced by `const_iterator cbegin();`... begging the need for `const_iterator begin();`?

Comment: Think of a container class member variable used in a `const`  function. How would you access `begin()` without a `const_iterator`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001410/what-is-the-reason-behind-cbegin-cend provides the answer to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of the const overloads of std::begin and end?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33586029/1708801)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, there is a simple historic reason: the original C++ standard didn't use `cbegin()` and only had the two `begin()` overloads. It was felt that sometimes it would be useful to obtain `const_iterator`s to a non-`const` sequence and `cbegin()` and `cend()` were added (despite `begin()` and `end()` *members* actually being ill-advise: we'd be much better of if they were just non-member functions). That is, if the `const` overload of `begin()` had been removed when `cbegin()` was introduced, at lot of code would have been broken.

From a practical point of view it is also desirable to have both the non-`const` and the `const` overloads:

- use of `begin()` and `cbegin()` in normal code *could* be done it would be quite annoying to actually do so when changing the `const`ness of objects
- more importantly, in generic (templatized) code where sequence could be either `const` or non-`const` it would be necessary to use some dance to to use the correct overload.

Answer (score 2):

There's probably no place in the language where you couldn't give something a different name; this is just a little act of kindness, a bit like `size()` and `length()` on `std::string`.

Remembering to use `cbegin` when working on a `const` container is a PITA, so the `const_iterator begin() const` is useful. At the same time, when I'm explicitly interested in obtaining a `const` iterator, without `cbegin` I'd have to do something convoluted like `((const std::vector<int> &)vec).begin()`, which is certainly less readable/writable than `vec.cbegin()`.

Now, you could argue that there are places where little acts of kindness like this are more sorely needed (and which scale better — supporting all the combinations of regular/reverse/const iterators quickly makes the interface explode), and I would certainly agree with you.

Incidentally, having the `const_iterator begin` avoids the need for other fiddling to make the range-based for loop work correctly on `const` objects.