# Member function .begin() and std::begin()

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, move, move-semantics

Calling the member function `.begin()` of `std::vector` and `std::begin()` on rvalues result in different outputs, as the following test shows:

```
vector<int> a{ 1, 2, 3 };

vector<int>::iterator it1 = move(a).begin(); // OK
vector<int>::const_iterator it2 = move(a).begin(); // OK

vector<int>::iterator it3 = begin(move(a)); // Error!
vector<int>::const_iterator it4 = begin(move(a)); // OK
```

Here is my understanding: `std::begin()` calls `const&` overload (since it lack `&&` overload), and therefore, it return a `const_iterator` object. So, the returned value can be assigned to `const_iterator` but not `iterator.`

1. Is my understanding correct?
2. Why does `std::begin()` not have an rvalue overload?

Just a note that I used `move(a)` to demonstrate calling `.begin()` and `std::begin()` on rvalues. Of course, it can be replaced by any rvalue object for which `.begin()` and `std::begin()` are well defined.

**Edit:** Here is the real example showing where I encountered this issue. I've simplified a lot just to convey the idea where `std::begin()` is called on an rvalue. So, since `row_matrix` is a proxy class, there shouldn't be any problem calling `begin` and `end` on rvalues since the underlying object is identical.

```
class matrix_row;
class row_iterator;

class matrix {
public:
    matrix_row row(int i);
    // other members
};  

class matrix_row { // <- proxy class representing a row of matrix
public:
    row_iterator begin();
    row_iterator end();
    // other members
private:
    int row_;
    matrix& matrix_;
};

class row_iterator {
    // defined everything needed to qualify as a valid iterator 
};

matrix m(3,4);

for(auto x = m.row(1).begin(); x != m.row(1).end(); ++x) {
    *x /=2; // OK
}

for(auto x = begin(m.row(1)); x != end(m.row(1)); ++x) {
    *x /= 2; // Error
}
```

Comment: [That `std::begin()` accepts an rvalue at all is probably more of an accident than intentional design.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33586029/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-const-overloads-of-stdbegin-and-end)

Comment: *"Why does `std::begin()` not have an rvalue overload?"* What would that do? Does not sound all too useful to me.

Comment: `begin` isn't terribly useful if the underlying range no longer exists, so it doesn't seem useful for it to have an rvalue overload.

Comment: I just updated my answer with a real (though incomplete) example on how I encountered such an issue.

Comment: normally you would not write code like `m.row(1).begin(); x != m.row(1).end();`, because each call to `row(1)` returns a different object.  In general this is undefined . You make a special case but that has different semantics to normal iterators, which could explain why it's not supported (and you should avoid doing it).

Answer (score 3):

Until recently, overloading `.begin()` by rvalue/lvalue-ness of the invoking object was not possible.

When it was added, retrofitting such changes into the standard library could, in theory, break existing code.

Breaking existing code is bad, bad enough that legacy quirks are left in barring reasonably strong evidence that such code does not exist, that there would be clear diagnostics, and/or the effect of the change is really useful.

So `.begin()` ignores rvalueness of its `*this`.

There is no such restriction on `std::begin`, other than possibly wishing compatibility with `.begin()`.

In theory, standard containers don't have a proper respose to being called with `std::begin` in an rvalue context.  The "proper" way of interacting with `std::move` or rvalues is that you aren't supposed to care about the state of the moved-from object after the call completes.

This means (logically) you can only get one of the two iterators out (begin or end).

What the proper semantics are in this case is a big puzzling.  I have written adaptors that, in this situation (a pseudo-begin/end call on an rvalue) generate move iterators (for example), but doing that in general is very surprising, and I think it is a bad move in the end.

Answer (score -1):

23.2.1/12 states:

> Unless otherwise specified (either explicitly or by defining a
>   function in terms of other functions), invoking a container member
>   function or passing a container as an argument to a library function
>   shall not invalidate iterators to, or change the values of, objects
>   within that container.

[DR 2321](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/lwg-active.html#2321) also wants to make it explicit:

> no move constructor (or move assignment operator when
>   `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value`
>   is true) of a container (except for `array`) invalidates any
>   references, pointers, or iterators referring to the elements of the
>   source container. *[Note:* The `end()` iterator does not refer to any
>   element, so it may be invalidated. — *end note]*

Of course this would only be useful if you were moving *into* a different container, but you're not.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?