# Performing some operation on std::move(x)

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Let's get the formalities out of the way.

> 17.3.28 valid but unspecified state [defns.valid]
>
> an object state that is not specified except that the object's
>   invariants are met and operations on the object behave as specified
>   for its type
>
> [ *Example:* If an object `x` of type `std::vector<int>` is
>   in a valid but unspecified state, `x.empty()` can be called
>   unconditionally, and `x.front()` can be called only if `x.empty()` returns
>   false.  — *end example* ]

Some users have suggested that `std::move(x).something()` is nonsensical. But I'm having trouble understanding the difference between `std::move(x).something()` and `y = std::move(x); y.something()`. Observe:

```
// -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC
std::vector<int> v;
v.pop_back();
// Error: attempt to access an element in an empty container.
```

Now we want to try our nonsensical case:

```
std::vector<int> v(10);
std::move(v).pop_back();
```

No error. This must be the "valid but unspecified" everyone's talking about, but let's keep going.

```
std::vector<int> v(10);
std::cout << std::move(v).size();
auto v2 = std::move(v);
std::cout << v.size();
```

This prints `100`. That's not too surprising. `std::move` is just a cast, it doesn't actually perform the job of the move constructor.

Am I missing something or is `std::move(x).something()` still non-sensical (other than being a no-op)?

---

For reference, see the comments on [Member function .begin() and std::begin()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37262329/member-function-begin-and-stdbegin) as well as the upvoted answer.

The following example suggests that `v` is not moved from:

```
template< class C >
auto begin( C&& c ) -> decltype(c.begin())
{
    return c.begin();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(10);
    std::vector<int>::iterator it3 = begin(std::move(v));
    std::cout << v.size();
}
```

Outputs `10`.

Comment: `std::move(v)` doesn't do anything to `v`. `std::move(v).pop_back();` has the same effect as `v.pop_back();` (although that cannot be generalized to all types.). The quote you posted is missing some context.

Comment: @juanchopanza My context comes from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37262329/member-function-begin-and-stdbegin). Comments like "`begin` isn't terribly useful if the underlying range no longer exists, so it doesn't seem useful for it to have an rvalue overload." and "In theory, standard containers don't have a proper respose to being called with `std::begin` in an rvalue context. The "proper" way of interacting with `std::move` or rvalues is that you aren't supposed to care about the state of the moved-from object after the call completes." seem to suggest something I'm missing.

Comment: @juanchopanza In other words, `std::begin(std::move(x))` or `std::move(x).begin()` are the same as `std::begin(x)` or `x.begin()` right? So where is the logic coming from?

Comment: I mean that the quote most likely doesn't refer to an expression such as `std::move(x)`. It probably refers to using `x` after `y = std::move(x);`

Comment: You're misunderstanding @KerrekSB's comment. It's not about `begin(move(x))`. It's about `begin(some_function_that_returns_a_range())`. The latter isn't terribly useful since you don't have a way of actually getting the end iterator or actually extending the lifetime of the container long enough to use the begin iterator that you got.

Comment: "Some users have suggested that `std::move(x).something()` is nonsensical." Citation needed? It's not nonsensical.

Comment: @Barry, indeed. If the something method has `&` and `&&` overloads, then `std::move(x).something()` will call a different overload than `x.something()`. `void something() & { .... }` and `void something() && { .... }`

Answer (score 6):

`std::move` doesn't do anything to the object! All it does is *casting* an object to an ravlue, so that it can be bound by rvalue reference.

Any modifications to the object are done by corresponding move constructor or move assingnment operator. If none are called, nothing happens at all.

Comment: @Barry agree, will fix.

Answer (score 0):

> But I'm having trouble understanding the difference between `std::move(x).something()` and `y = std::move(x); y.something()`

With (note the `&`/`&&` after `const`)

```
struct S
{
    void foo() const & {std::cout << "l-value this\n"; }
    void foo() const && {std::cout << "r-value this\n"; }
};
```

You got:

```
S tmp;
std::move(tmp).foo(); // "r-value this

S x = std::move(tmp);
x.foo(); // "l-value this
```