# Perfect forwarding iterators: is it too much?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17, perfect-forwarding

In C++, the constness of an object is *forwarded* through iterators. `std::begin(a)` will generally return `A::iterator` if `a` is not const, `A::const_iterator` if `a` is const.

I tried to extend this concept to *move behaviour*, in order to have better generic code. The basic idea is something like this:

```cpp
struct A {
  using value_type = std::string;
  using iterator = AIter<A>;
  using const_iterator = AIter<A const>;
  using move_iterator = AIter<A &&>;

  iterator begin() &;
  iterator end() &;
  const_iterator begin() const &;
  const_iterator end() const &;
  move_iterator begin() &&;
  move_iterator end() &&;
};

template <typename A> struct AIter {
  using a_type = A;
  using value_type = typename std::decay_t<A>::value_type;
  using reference = std::conditional_t<
      std::is_rvalue_reference_v<A>, value_type &&,
      std::conditional_t<std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<A>>,
                         value_type const &, value_type &>>;
};
```

It is a bit convoluted, especially the conditional type in the iterator. The concept is simply that the type of the iterator completely depends on the *reference type* of `A`.

Unfortunately, the problem arises when, instead of directly using member functions, I try to use `std::begin` and `std::end` (and all the similar ones), because they are not designed to work in a *perfect forwarding* manner. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/EAmHVc) you can find a small demo on compiler explorer, if you want to make some tests.

Given the current situation, my point is:

- Am I asking too much to the standard iterators? Are there any *unexpected* behaviour of this approach? I have never seen something like `std::begin(std::move(a))` around (you generally use `std::make_move_iterator` to do so), but in generic code I think that using `std::begin(std::forward<A>(a))` could be useful... or not?
- I don't have a clear idea of how this approach would work with C++20 ranges. What do you think?
- If you consider that this approach could be valuable, do you think that it could be better using the `.begin()` method or a custom free function that performs *perfect forwarding*? Something like in the link to compiler explorer.

*EDIT*: Nelfeal found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37262329/member-function-begin-and-stdbegin/37263161#37263161) that is very related to mine.

Comment: *Const* versions of iterators are important for const-correctness. I'm pretty sure *move* versions wouldn't have any advantage over `std::make_move_iterator`, even in generic contexts. If you see a good use case one, you probably should include it in your question.

Comment: For "generic context", I intend code [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/FuhagQ) (a dumb one in this case). As you can see, using the standard behaviour I must use compile-time conditionals in order to perform the operation one would expect.

Comment: "a dumb one in this case" because `from_to` doesn't do anything more than what `std::transform` does? These kinds of algorithms are defined, at least in the standard library, for iterators instead of containers. I can't think of a example that isn't a "dumb one".

Comment: I have a real test case in which I am using this behaviour. It is convoluted and it does not make any sense to create complex example just to demonstrate that "there is an application". Asserting that "there is no possible useful usage" is a bit strong, and until you can give a valid proof it is just your opinion IMHO.

Comment: Of course it's my opinion, I've never said otherwise. But without a "real" test case, even a convoluted one, **I** fail to see a useful application, and **I** doubt anyone else who stumbles upon your question would see one.

Comment: @Nelfeal [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4c21d282a847807) you will find a code with two functions to _fuse/zip_ the content of two containers of containers into a single one. The main fn is mainly related to how you can use them. The function that works with iterators can be cumbersome to use, the other is limited but pretty straightforward to use. Both of them need to use "constexpr if" for the reason I already discussed. As you can see, it can be useful and it is totally not "dumb". This should be pretty convincing.

Comment: I don't see why you pass the inner container by forwarding references in the lambda. I may be missing something, but if you pass by value, the move constructors should take care of moves when applicable. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9b852a3b63e400b) (I only modified `fuse_containers`, all your tests seem to pass). Anyway, that's not really your question. To me, your move iterators are pretty pointless because you can't call both `begin` and `end` on a single rvalue, and because you know at the call site whether or not you want a move.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if this is causing you confusion, but in your example function `get_fused_container`, calling `begin` on the argument `a` would use the "normal", lvalue version, even if `A` had a `move_iterator begin() &&` method like in your question: [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8459ef06b6a1d84e).

Comment: You missed the perfect forwarding: [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d6aede550fcf7f4)

Comment: Oh, right. So you would like `std::begin(std::forward<T>(a))` to be equivalent to `std::move_iterator(std::begin(a))`, then. Wouldn't a couple of custom free functions `begin` and `end` (probably outside the `std` namespace) that do just that be sufficient?

Comment: This is exactly what I said in the question, it is one possibility.

Comment: My bad then, I originally thought you were asking something else in your first bullet point. You may want to ask another question like "why don't `std::begin` and `std::end` produce move iterators?". I can't say for sure, but I'm going to guess there is a corner case with "unexpected behavior", as you say. However, for your own use, I would argue that writing a specialized free function is better than writing additional methods.

Comment: Thanks. If you eventually came up with a case that does not work like you would expect, just let me know ;).

Comment: [Worth reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37263161/3854570). The question of C++20 ranges is interesting; when they get introduced, containers might have an rvalue version for range accessors. But to be honest, I'm still not convinced it would be that useful.

Comment: Good catch @Nelfeal!!!